# Knockout mapping not working for JSON object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout-mapping-plugin

```
function Employee() {
 return @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)) 
};

function EmployeeList(Employee) {
 var map = ko.mapping.fromJS(Employee); return map; 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 var obj = { emp: ko.observable(new EmployeeList(new Employee)) }; 
ko.applyBindings(obj); 
});
```

Comment: in what way is this "not working"? You really need to give a bit more context here...

Comment: so when i tried to use emp in my code and I didnt see any empployee name appearing whereas I see json data available. <ui data-bind="foreach: emp">
    <li>
        Name <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    </li>
</ui>

Comment: And what JSON is being rendered by your HTML helper? Are you sure it's valid?

Comment: yes its {"Name":"test", "Address":"test"}

Comment: thanks your solution worked. so I tried to optimize the in better way but then I bump into another set of error. would you mind helping me - this is what i am messing with -

Comment: What's the new problem, was there supposed to be a link in your last comment?

Comment: so I am trying to achieve something like this - function Products() {
    data: ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))),
    editaction: '',
    deleteaction: ''
}
            
$(document).ready(function () {
   
    ko.applyBindings(Products);
});

Comment: Best thing to do is post this as a new question - just bear in mind to give all the context up front this time :) You can comment me a link to the new question, of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an `observableArray`, which the ko mapping plugin is already creating for you, and map in an actual array of objects, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DsqqC/1) :

```
function Employee() {
    return  [{Name:"test", Address:"test"}] ;
};

function EmployeeList(Employee) {
 var map = ko.mapping.fromJS(Employee); 
    return map(); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 var obj = { emp: EmployeeList(Employee) }; 
ko.applyBindings(obj);
});
```

Note how I changed your `EmployeeList` function to return `map()` and not `map` - map is a function, you want to return the *actual values* wrapped by that function  - this allows you to specify obj much more cleanly - no need to wrap map in yet another `observableArray`...

Hope that helps...